# Make javascript method work in all cases (before and after ajax calls)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, http-delete

I'm working on laravel 5.5, where I want to do a page with just a table showing all the accessory_type items. With a basic one to many relation to the accessory table.

On this page I have a field to create new entries with a basic Ajax post, all was inside a `$(document).ready()` , here is the code :

```
var name = $('#name').val();
$.Ajax({
        url: '/accessory-type',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name: name},
        success: function (data) {
            $.Ajax({
                url: null,
                type: 'get',
                success: function (data) {
                    var my_rows = $(data).find('table').html();
                    $('.accessory_type-table').html(my_rows);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is : I want to delete a row by clicking an icon or something like that, but if I place my code outside of a `$(document).ajaxComplete` the code doesn't work after an Ajax call. And if I place inside the `$(document).ajaxComplete`, the code doesn't work without an Ajax call.

The code is exactly the same, so I don't want to have it twice.

If I create a function for it the problem persists, where do I can place my `click()` method to make it work in all cases ?

Here is the code I want to call :

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('.fa-trash').click(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.Ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "/accessory-type/" + $(this).attr('id'),
            success: function (data) {
                $.Ajax({
                    url: null,
                    type: 'get',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var table = $(data).find('table').html();
                        $('.accessory_type-table').html(table);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })
})
```

I'm in training so any help/best practice/advice or anything is good, don't hesitate ! :)
Thanks for you help

Comment: Hello, can you elaborate on "the code doesn't work without an Ajax call"? [`$(document).ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)'s parameter function should be where you put your event handlers in 99% cases.

Comment: All the code is inside a `$(document).ready`. Inside this I have my `$(document).ajaxComplete`. But if I dont create a new entry with the ajax post before, that don't handle the `click()` method. I have try with some console.log but the code isn't reached before a request.